# Maximum recursion depth exceeded while deleting in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following Folder model which represents all the folders I have inside a directory :

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_folder = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='childrens')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Folder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.pk is not None:
            self.initial_filepath = self.filepath()
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        on_creation = self.pk is None
        
        if on_creation:
            os.mkdir(self.filepath())
            
        else:
            os.rename(self.initial_filepath, self.filepath())
        super(Folder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        shutil.rmtree(self.filepath(), ignore_errors=True)
        super(Folder, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def filepath(self):
        if not self.parent_folder:
            return f'media/scripts/{self.folder_name}'
        else:
            return f'{self.parent_folder.filepath()}/{self.folder_name}'
```

The problem is, when I'm in the admin page and I try to delete a folder, if it has subfolders in it (i.e. if the folder I'm deleting is the *parent_folder* of another folder instance) it doesn't delete any of the selected folders and returns a RecursionError after a few seconds.

I've checked my code, and I don't see any recursion loop inside my own code, and I didn't manage to determine where it was coming from.

I've also overriden the **delete_queryset** method in my admin.py but the issue doesn't seem to come from there as it still doesn't work if I try to delete my parent folder from inside the page to modify my folder.

```
class FolderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                
    def delete_queryset(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.delete()
        queryset.delete()
```

The folders are deleted on my computer so the delete method is called, no problem. My guess is that it's coming from my ForeignKey but I have absolutely no idea how to solve this issue.

---

**EDIT :**
I just found out that there was a recursion in the error that can help to solve my problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\AppliScripts\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 173, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\AppliScripts\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]

During handling of the above exception ('parent_folder'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\AppliScripts\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 173, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "C:\Users\stephane.bernardelli\Documents\AppliScripts\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
```

The `During the handling of the above exception...` part is repeated like 30 times before the traceback changes to something else.

Comment: seems like it probably comes from this `self.parent_folder.filepath()`... that looks like where the recursion would be happening (i.e. `filepath` method calls same method on its parent), so that implies that the negative case `if not self.parent_folder` is never found to stop the recursion

Comment: This method works fine, I'm pretty sure it doesn't come from it, I've tried it many times and it always returns the correct value, with the correct case being executed.
However, I just found something by looking at the error traceback that for some reason I didn't see before, so I'll edit my post accordingly